# how to use max-width

Tags: html, css

I have currently got a school project where we need to make a website, just for fun tho! Anyways I have made a website with max-width, it works pretty good! only when the screen is small my buttons go over my image. Does anyone have a solution to this?

https://jsfiddle.net/fvwk2zr9/

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){ 
.float-left {float: none;}
```

Coen

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

You can drop down the content below the nav by first creating a new div to group the content outside of the div, with the class name "container" (This is a common web development practice):

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <img class="banner" src="http://i184.photobucket.com/albums/x286/tkReaper/ReaperBanner.jpg"/>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix text-border">
        <p><img class="img-text" src="stadenesch.jpg"/>Hoi! Leuk dat je langskomt bij Stad &amp; Esch web oefeningen! Stad &amp; Esch staat voor maatwerk-onderwijs. Zeker bij informatica worden de lessen al in grote mate afgestemd op de persoonlijke voorkeuren van de leerlingen. Er is voor ieder wat wils. Met deze teksten gaan we de website volstoppen om iets te zien van de mogelijkheden van CSS in combinatie met HTML bestanden </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then add the new class "container" to your "@media screen and (max-width: 600px)" in the CSS, along with the attribute "margin-top" (220px from the top seemed to give the result you're after):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){ 
    .float-left {float: none;}
    .container {margin-top: 220px}
}
```

NOTE: This is a quick, more static way of doing what you're after, if you add more items to your navigation bar, you'll need to increase the number on "margin-top"